# Will iPhone SE price likely be reduced 1 year after its debut?

Tags: iphone

the iPhone SE came out last March, and rumour is that it [won't be updated this year](http://appleinsider.com/articles/16/11/04/apple-unlikely-to-refresh-iphone-se-in-first-half-of-2017-analyst-says). Will it likely see a price drop this cycle? Is it best to hold off till March to buy one?

Comment: Although its not certain without inside information I don't see this question as opinion-based; anyone with knowledge of Apples historical pricing approach can answer it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Apple knows the answer to this question.

While one may think that Apple could lower the price it could in fact go up: Depending on the country you are living prices have been increased in the past due to currency fluctuations.

IMO it's unlikely that we will see a price drop for the iPhone SE. For Apple it's a device with a really low profit margin compared to other products. It has most of the iPhone 6s' internal specs so Apple is in no hurry to upgrade it either.

I think if you *need* a new iPhone because your old one is broken, buy it now.